# Ember.js only binds the property called 'name' in my model in a HandleBars template

Tags: ember.js

This is my model file with fixtures:

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Game.FIXTURES = [
{ 
    id: 1,
    name: '-TEMPIN-',
    description: 'Test',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.kefsensei.com'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: '¡Oh My GlobZ Mucho Party!',
    description: 'Test',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCBc2mWXeu4&'
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: '90s Arcade Racer',
    description: 'Test',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.kefsensei.com'
}
];
```

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="/sass/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="games">
      <div class="container_12">
        <ul class="games">
          {{#each}}
            <li>
              <div class="description grid_8">
                <h1>{{name}}</h1>
                <p>Description:{{description}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="categorization grid_4">
              </div>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script src="/javascripts/vendor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my router:
    App.Router.map(function () {
        this.resource('games', { path: '/' });
    });

```
App.GamesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
        return this.store.find('game');
    }
});
```

No matter what I do the only property of my model that is bound and displayed when I navigate to the root of my application is the 'name' property.

If I change the name of my 'name' property, it no longer binds. The description property does not bind.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define the properties on the model

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    websiteUrl: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/101/edit